# I have gotten three different entry points which one is the correct one?

Tags: c++, process, entry-point

I am trying to get the entry point of an executable game file.
I have used 3 ways, 2 programs, and 1 c++ code.

[image]

C++ Code:

```
HMODULE GetModuleHandle(CONST CHAR* ModuleName, DWORD ProcessId) {
    HMODULE hModule = 0;
    HANDLE Snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, ProcessId);
    MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry32 = { 0 };
    ModuleEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

    if (Module32First(Snapshot, &ModuleEntry32)) {
        do {
            if (strcmp(ModuleEntry32.szModule, ModuleName) == 0) {
                hModule = ModuleEntry32.hModule;
                break;
            }
        } while (Module32Next(Snapshot, &ModuleEntry32));
    }
    CloseHandle(Snapshot);
    return hModule;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    PROCESSENTRY32 ps;
    MODULEINFO mi;
    HANDLE hsnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    ps.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    while (Process32Next(hsnap, &ps)) {
        if (strcmp("ms.exe", ps.szExeFile) == 0)
            break;
    }
    CloseHandle(hsnap);
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, ps.th32ProcessID);
    if (!process) exit(0);
    GetModuleInformation(process, GetModuleHandle("ms.exe", ps.th32ProcessID), &mi, sizeof(MODULEINFO));
    std::cout << std::hex << mi.EntryPoint;
    return 0;
}
```

**How do I know which one is the correct entry point?**
Note that what I care about is the C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the last two seems to be right **x38274** where x is base
which would normally change during evey run because of ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization)

and your code as is doesnt seem to correct ?
GetModuleBaseAddress  doesn't seem to be a documented Windows API
googling shows it return a DWORD ? NOT a HMODULE as required by GetModuleInformation()
HMODULE in x64 is 8 bytes wide while a DWORD is 4 bytes
there may be truncation problem (have you compiled with all warnings enabled and corrected the warnings

anyway shown below is a sample getmba.cpp compiled and linked as getmba.exe in winx-x64-vs2019 with

```
cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /Od /EHsc getmba.cpp /link /release

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
int main(void)
{
    MODULEINFO mi = {0};
    HANDLE curproc = GetCurrentProcess();
    HMODULE curmod = GetModuleHandleA("getmba.exe");
    if (curproc != NULL && curmod != NULL)
    {
        GetModuleInformation(curproc, curmod, &mi, sizeof(MODULEINFO));
        printf("Entry Point = %p\nBase Of Dll = %p\n", mi.EntryPoint , mi.lpBaseOfDll );
    }
}
```

executing the compiled binary gives

```
Entry Point = 00007FF7EE14143C
Base Of Dll = 00007FF7EE140000
```

confirming with dumpbin

```
dumpbin /headers getmba.exe | find "entry"
            143C entry point (000000014000143C) mainCRTStartup
```

Comment: It is my fault, the `GetModuleBaseAddress` is a custom function I have forgotten to change its name. I have updated my code.